# Istio: How to modify the h2UpgradePolicy globally?

Tags: kubernetes-ingress, http2, istio, istio-kiali

I want up upgrade all incoming http 1.1 connections to http2 in Istio. I understand how to achieve this via destination rules for a particular namespace and pod.

However, I want to upgrade all connections in service mesh from http1.1 too http2. Even the documentation recommends this, if Istio sidecar is auto injected [here](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/istio.mesh.v1alpha1/#MeshConfig-H2UpgradePolicy).

> if sidecar is installed on all pods in the mesh, then this should be set to UPGRADE.

Can I update the "istio" ConfigMap under "Istio-system" namespace?

If yes, what would the entry look like?

If no, please suggest How can I achieve this with minimal effort?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, you will set it in the The `configMap` istio, and it would like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  mesh: |-
    accessLogEncoding: TEXT
    accessLogFile: /dev/stdout
    accessLogFormat: ""
    h2UpgradePolicy: UPGRADE        #<- here
    defaultConfig:
      concurrency: 2
      configPath: ./etc/istio/proxy
```

Now, it is a little tricky to see that it works. I sent four requests; two of them without `h2UpgradePolicy` parameter, and two of them with `h2UpgradePolicy: UPGRADE`. But my all four of my requests from the client looked like this:

```
$ kubectl exec -it curler -- curl -I demo.istio
Defaulting container name to curler.
Use 'kubectl describe pod/curler -n default' to see all of the containers in this pod.
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
server: envoy
date: Mon, 22 Jun 2020 13:05:53 GMT
content-type: text/html
content-length: 612
last-modified: Tue, 26 May 2020 15:00:20 GMT
etag: "5ecd2f04-264"
accept-ranges: bytes
x-envoy-upstream-service-time: 1
```

I sent the requests from outside the mesh, as from within I was getting HTTP2 by default. So, in my case mTLS was disabled, but that's irrelevant.

To see that it works, you would check the logs of the downstream proxy:

```
...
[2020-06-22T13:03:03.942Z] "HEAD / HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "-" 0 0 0 0 "-" "curl/7.59.0" "a7c32d21-dcea-95da-b7c1-67c5783a1641" "demo.istio" "127.0.0.1:80" inbound|80|http|demo.istio.svc.cluster.local 127.0.0.1:33180 192.168.72.186:80 192.168.66.168:34814 outbound_.80_._.demo.istio.svc.cluster.local default
[2020-06-22T13:03:05.245Z] "HEAD / HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "-" 0 0 0 0 "-" "curl/7.59.0" "409b3432-365f-94fe-87cd-8a85b586b42d" "demo.istio" "127.0.0.1:80" inbound|80|http|demo.istio.svc.cluster.local 127.0.0.1:60952 192.168.72.186:80 192.168.66.168:34830 outbound_.80_._.demo.istio.svc.cluster.local default
[2020-06-22T13:03:36.732Z] "HEAD / HTTP/2" 200 - "-" "-" 0 0 0 0 "-" "curl/7.59.0" "45dd94e5-6f29-9114-b09f-bda065dfd1eb" "demo.istio" "127.0.0.1:80" inbound|80|http|demo.istio.svc.cluster.local 127.0.0.1:33180 192.168.72.186:80 192.168.66.168:35120 outbound_.80_._.demo.istio.svc.cluster.local default
[2020-06-22T13:03:38.743Z] "HEAD / HTTP/2" 200 - "-" "-" 0 0 0 0 "-" "curl/7.59.0" "79e72286-f247-9ed0-b510-2819a886c7f9" "demo.istio" "127.0.0.1:80" inbound|80|http|demo.istio.svc.cluster.local 127.0.0.1:33180 192.168.72.186:80 192.168.66.168:35120 outbound_.80_._.demo.istio.svc.cluster.local default
```

**VERY IMPORTANT:** To make it work, the service in front if the downstream peer, must have named port, and it must be called `http`

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: demo
spec:
  ports:
  - name: http      #<- this parameter is mandatory to upgrade to HTTP2
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 80
  selector:
    app: nginx
```

Comment: I've captured the details in this blog post. https://medium.com/google-cloud/boost-istio-service-mesh-by-upgrading-to-http-2-part-1-65e73da57bc4