# Is it possible to enable HTTP/2 with TLS termination on Istio Gateway?

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, tls1.2, http2, istio

Is it possible to enable HTTP/2 with TLS(mTLS) termination on Istio Gateway ? And then forward traffic  to the application with HTTP/2

Comment: If your web-server supports HTTP2 protocol then there shouldn't be any issues.  There is [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62515383/11977760) created by @suren about that, you can follow it to modify the h2UpgradePolicy globally to upgrade all incoming http 1.1 connections to http2.

Comment: when the http/2 request comes, the tсp connection will be kept until isitio ingress gateway or untill web-application?

Comment: As far as I know the connection should be kept until wep-app. Ingress gateway will be responsible for pass the request through if it's http2, or to upgrade it from http to http2 if it's http.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. Http 2 between your services is negotiated in the [ALPN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application-Layer_Protocol_Negotiation) (during mTLS handshake).

You can then forward traffic from sidecar proxy to your application container with Http 2 by setting your [service port name (protocol selection)](https://istio.io/latest/docs/ops/configuration/traffic-management/protocol-selection/) to `http2`.

An example service for your app:

```
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: myapp
spec:
  ports:
  - number: 8080
    name: http2    # protocol selection by name - important to have http2 here
```

Answer (score 0):

If your web-server supports HTTP2 protocol then there shouldn't be any issues.

> when the http/2 request comes, the tсp connection will be kept until isitio ingress gateway or untill web-application?

As far as I know the connection should be kept until wep-app. Ingress gateway will be responsible for pass the request through if it's http2, or to upgrade it from http1.1 to http2 if it's http1.1.

---

As @suren mentioned in his answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62496237/istio-how-to-modify-the-h2upgradepolicy-globally/62515383#62515383)

You can set h2UpgradePolicy in the The istio configMap and it's gonna upgrade all incoming http 1.1 connections to http2, so only connections with http2 will pass through.

> VERY IMPORTANT: To make it work, the service in front if the downstream peer, must have named port, and it must be called http

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: demo
spec:
  ports:
  - name: http      #<- this parameter is mandatory to upgrade to HTTP2
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 80
  selector:
    app: nginx
```

---

Additionally there are is a way to achieve this with [Destination Rule](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/destination-rule/) for a particular namespace and pod, you can achieve that with [ConnectionPoolSettings.HTTPSettings.H2UpgradePolicy](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/destination-rule/#ConnectionPoolSettings-HTTPSettings), which upgrade http1.1 connections to http2.